# using the II operator in a Oracle query within Powershell

Tags: oracle, powershell, plsql

I'm attempting to define a $queryString to be used against an Oracle database.  I also need to be able to concatenate some of the query with the || operator.  The problem I believe is that Powershell sees this as the Pipeline operator.  I've also tried using the escape in the form of both \| and ''| but neither seem to work.  for reference, here is the query I am using.

```
$queryString = 'select v.npa || v.calling_number phone_number, v.location, v.customer_name '
$queryString += 'from voip_validate v '
$queryString += 'left outer join phone_numbers p '
$queryString += 'on v.npa || v.calling_number = p.area_code || p.phone_prefix || p.phone_suffix '
$queryString += 'left outer join mv_dps_buildings b '
$queryString += 'on b.dps_building_number = p.dps_building_number '
$queryString += 'where p.area_code is null '
$queryString += 'and p.phone_prefix is null '
$queryString += 'and p.phone_suffix is null; '
```

Comment: What doesn't work? I run it in PS3.0 and PS2.0 and it returns a string including the `||` parts. Are you on PS1.0?

Comment: I'm using PS2.0.  I kept getting an error saying it was missing the FROM and I kept attributing it to misinterpreting the || as a pipe instead of concat.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use `here-string` (http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee692792.aspx) :

```
$queryString = @'
select v.npa || v.calling_number phone_number, v.location, v.customer_name 
from voip_validate v 
left outer join phone_numbers p 
on v.npa || v.calling_number = p.area_code || p.phone_prefix || p.phone_suffix 
left outer join mv_dps_buildings b 
on b.dps_building_number = p.dps_building_number 
where p.area_code is null 
and p.phone_prefix is null 
and p.phone_suffix is null; 
'@

PS>$queryString
select v.npa || v.calling_number phone_number, v.location, v.customer_name
from voip_validate v
left outer join phone_numbers p
on v.npa || v.calling_number = p.area_code || p.phone_prefix || p.phone_suffix
left outer join mv_dps_buildings b
on b.dps_building_number = p.dps_building_number
where p.area_code is null
and p.phone_prefix is null
and p.phone_suffix is null;
```